# How to remove empty jenkins job?

Tags: jenkins

I recently noticed an entry in the list of jobs on our jenkins server that is empty and I'm not sure how to dig deeper.

[image]

I explored the jenkins server web page for another way to access the details of the nameless job with no success. I was logged in with an account that has access to job details.

Browsing the jobs folder on the machine running the jenkins instance didn't reveal any obvious source of the nameless job.

I also tried running this script from the Script Console

```
Jenkins.instance.getAllItems(AbstractItem.class).each
{
    println(it.fullName)
};
```

And it generated the expected list of jobs with no surprises.

Comment: Well, that's just bizarre. Have you tried looking at the file system to see the name of the job - ${JENKINS_©HOME}/jobs. Or try using a groovy script to list it. Probably a non-printing character.

Comment: Seems like a Jenkins bug - but perhaps there is some weird directory under `~/Jenkins/jobs` on the physical machine?